# mapping of one column with another two

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas Dataframe with three columns that follows this structure:

```
Employee        email              Manager 
Smith       asmith@example.com     Johnson          
Doe         jdoe@example.com       Smith           
Johnson     jjohnson@example.com   Doe
...         ...                    ...
```

And I need to add a column named "Manager's email, with the email of the Employee's Manager.

```
Employee        email              Manager    Manager's Email 
Smith       asmith@example.com     Johnson    jjohnson@example.com        
Doe         jdoe@example.com       Smith      asmith@example.com        
Johnson     jjohnson@example.com   Doe        jdoe@example.com
...         ...                    ...        ...
```

So for example, for the Employee 'Smith' , since his Manager is 'Johnson', the value of the 'Manager's Email' for that row would be the email of the Employee 'Johnson'

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pandas.DataFrame.merge](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
>>> dfN = pd.merge(df, df, how='left', left_on='Manager', right_on='Employee', suffixes=['',"_m"])
>>> del dfN['Employee_m']
>>> del dfN['Manager_m']
>>> dfN = dfN.rename(columns={'email_m':"Manager's email"})
>>> dfN
  Employee  Manager                 email       Manager's email
0    Smith  Johnson    asmith@example.com  jjohnson@example.com
1      Doe    Smith      jdoe@example.com    asmith@example.com
2  Johnson      Doe  jjohnson@example.com      jdoe@example.com
```